# Python (and possibly others) - What is the escape character for a space?

Tags: python

Pretty simple concept, but I can't figure it out and could use some help. I need to check if a file in my Program Files directory exists, so I have the following:

```
import os

if not os.path.exists('C:/Program Files/file_to_be_found'):
  print "ERROR: Not Found!"
else:
  #rest of program...
```

However I know I can't do it this way. How can I write the path in the command to accept the space between "Program" and "Files"?

Comment: You don't need to escape the space. Python is not a shell, the value is not parsed for spaces.

Comment: You do have to delimit your string properly, though.

Comment: @Martijn Thanks I didn't realize that, I'm fairly new to Python and still trying to get the syntax down

Comment: A good habit I find is to use raw strings for things like file paths, so that the string is interpreted as-is. Just use an "r" in front of the string: `r'C:/Program Files/...'`

Comment: @Felix, you don't really need raw strings when using slashes.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, true, but raw strings even work when copy/pasting the path on Windows with backslashes. And since the OP is working on Windows there might be a chance that this happens ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the space is ok. and you are free to write the slash.

```
if os.path.exists('C:/Program Files'): print 'yes'
if os.path.exists(r'C:\Program Files'): print 'yes'
if os.path.exists('C:\\Program Files'): print 'yes'
```

all above are ok with or without a "r".

@nneonneo reminded that the second one is dangerous without "r" because the backslash is used to escape.

Comment: The middle one is dangerous. Consider `'C:\Users\tom'`. The `\t` is going to become a tab. The middle one should be written `r'C:\Program Files'` for safety.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Zhang, one quick follow-up, what exactly does the r inside the parens do? I'm not sure I've seen that before

Comment: @thnkwthprtls in short, the prefix r indicates a "raw string" in which all backslashes are simply backslashes with no escaping. check this doc for more detail: [link](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals)